# I want to download images from Python. What should I do?

Tags: python

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import urllib.request

path = (r"C:\Users\qpslt\Desktop\py\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(path)
driver.get("https://gall.dcinside.com/board/view/?id=baseball_new8&no=10131338&exception_mode=recommend&page=1")
html = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
soup_find_viewbox = soup.find("div", {"class" : "writing_view_box"})
soup_find_imgtag = soup_find_viewbox.findAll("img")
str_img_element = []
i = 0
for aa in soup_find_imgtag:
    str_img_element = str(aa).split("'")
    img_url = str_img_element[1].replace("amp;", "").replace("Pop", "")
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(img_url, "c:/test/" + str(i) + ".jpg")
```

It is a popular Korean community site.
There are a lot of pictures coming up here and I want to save them using Python.
I've tried a lot of methods using urlib, but I don't think site security is keeping us safe.
I'd appreciate it if you could suggest how to save it.

Comment: what is the criteria of your images

Comment: jpg, png, gif It's diverse
For example, I would like to save the png file on the link above.

Comment: show code and full error message. Don't expect that we will write all code for you. Did you use `beautifulsoup` or `lxml` to search links in code? Did you check if page doesn't uses JavaScript to load image - `urllib`/`requests`/`BeautifulSoup`/`lxm` can't run JavaScript and you may need `Selenium` to control browser which can run JavaScript.

Comment: @furas
I have modified my questionnaires to the source.
Search the image part with beautifulspoop to get a link to the image.
After that, I try to download the image, but the image is not downloaded.
I think we have prevented this crawling on the homepage.

Comment: I didn't run code yet but first  I would print `img_url` and use this url in browser - to check if url are correct. Second: i would check what I get in downloaded file - maybe there is HTML with message/warning or captcha for bots/script so it could explain problem. Third I would use header `Referer` if page blocks so "hot linking"

Comment: BTW: you should describe in question what you get - error message, or files which you can't open, or no images in folder.

Comment: @furas [link](https://gall.dcinside.com/board/view/?id=baseball_new8&no=10149193&exception_mode=recommend&page=1)
This link is the site where I want to save the image. 
Copying image addresses and downloading them to urlib doesn't work here.
I probably blocked this way on the homepage.
Can you give me one example or link to what the header is?
Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @furas I understand your question.
The site has protected the image hotlink.
Is there any way to download the hotlink image?

Comment: you have to uses header `Referer` with url of page in which are theses images and then server will think that browser try to get it, not script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This page check header `Referer` to block hotlinking

I used `requests` because it was easier for me to set this header.

BTW: I used Selenium function to get `img_url` so I don't need `BeautifulSoup`

```
from selenium import webdriver
import requests

path = r"C:\Users\qpslt\Desktop\py\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(path)
#driver = webdriver.Firefox()

url = "https://gall.dcinside.com/board/view/?id=baseball_new8&no=10131338&exception_mode=recommend&page=1"
driver.get(url)

images = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="writing_view_box"]//img')

for i, img in enumerate(images, 1):
    img_url = img.get_attribute('src')
    print(i, img_url)

    r = requests.get(img_url, headers={'Referer': url})

    with open("c:/test/{}.jpg".format(i), 'wb') as f:
         f.write(r.content)
```

Comment: thx bro :) 
Thanks to you, I solved it!

Answer (score 0):

As you have not give details of your problem it might help alot...

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Comment
from selenium import webdriver     
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
        driver.get('https://gall.dcinside.com/board/view/?id=baseball_new8&no=10131338&exception_mode=recommend&page=1')

    try:
            other_pic_list = []
            product_gallery = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('body')
            product_gallery_source_code = product_gallery.get_attribute("innerHTML")
            product_gallery_soup: BeautifulSoup = BeautifulSoup(product_gallery_source_code, 'html.parser')
            for pro_link_for in product_gallery_soup.findAll('img'):
                other_pic = pro_link_for['src']
                other_pic_list.append(slashparts[0])

            rd_other_pic_list = list(dict.fromkeys(other_pic_list))

        except IndexError as e:
            print('Images not avalable : ')

import requests
import os
pic_count=0
for url in rd_other_pic_list:
    with open(os.path.join(folder_path, pic_name), 'wb') as handle:
        try:
            headers = {
                'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:71.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/71.0'}
            r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
            if not r.ok:
                print("NO OK res" + str(r))
            else:
                pic_count = pic_count + 1
                handle.write(r.content)
                sleep(1)
        except Exception as e:
            print('Invalid URL with http')
        finally:
            pass
```